# DDRMenu not rendering everything in Razor template | DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, dotnetnuke

Problem with a simple Razor template. This should be rendering a list of my DNN pages:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu;
@using System.Dynamic; 
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage<dynamic>
@{
    var root = Model.Source.root;
}
@helper RenderNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes) {
    if (nodes.Count > 0) {
        <div id="dnnFooterMenu">
            <ul>
                @foreach (var node in nodes) {
                    if (node.HasChildren()) {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><b>@node.Text</b></a>
                            @RenderChildNodes(node.Children)
                        </li>
                    } 
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}
@helper RenderChildNodes(IList<MenuNode> nodes) {
    if (nodes.Count > 0) {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var node in nodes) {
                <li><a href="@node.Url">@node.Text</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
@RenderNodes(root.Children)
```

All it renders is this:

```
<div id="dnnFooterMenu">
    <ul>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The first and last pages have no children. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forgot I'd posted this... The problem was actually on the control in my .ascx; I had the wrong parent set for the menu:

`<dnn:menu id="dnnNav" menustyle="nav" nodeselector="`<strike>**Members**</strike>`" runat="server"/>`

So the MenuNode literally had no children to list.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely missing the cs file (typically "nav.cshtml") in the nav folder in the skin. It may not have been included in the install .zip folder.